# OOM Error while implementing image captioning model (especially LSTM)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, attention-model

I am implementing a model.

Till now I have implemented the following model:

```
class Attention(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, units):
        super(Attention, self).__init__()
        self.W1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units)
        self.W2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units)
        self.V = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)

    def call(self, features, hidden):
        # features(CNN_encoder output) shape == (batch_size, 64, embedding_dim)

        # hidden shape == (batch_size, hidden_size)
        # hidden_with_time_axis shape == (batch_size, 1, hidden_size)
        hidden_with_time_axis = tf.expand_dims(hidden, 1)

        # score shape == (batch_size, 64, hidden_size)
        score = tf.nn.tanh(self.W1(features) + self.W2(hidden_with_time_axis))

        # attention_weights shape == (batch_size, 64, 1)
        # you get 1 at the last axis because you are applying score to self.V
        attention_weights = tf.nn.softmax(self.V(score), axis=1)

        # context_vector shape after sum == (batch_size, hidden_size)
        context_vector = attention_weights * features
        context_vector = tf.reduce_sum(context_vector, axis=1)

        return context_vector, attention_weights

class CNN_Encoder(tf.keras.Model):
    # Since you have already extracted the features and dumped it using pickle
    # This encoder passes those features through a Fully connected layer
    def __init__(self, embedding_dim):
        super(CNN_Encoder, self).__init__()
        # shape after fc == (batch_size, 49, embedding_dim)
        self.fc = tf.keras.layers.Dense(embedding_dim)

    def call(self, x):
        x = self.fc(x)
        x = tf.nn.relu(x)
        # shape of x == (batch_size, 49, embedding_dim)
        return x

class RDN_Decoder(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, embedding_dim, units, vocab_size):
        super(RDN_Decoder, self).__init__()
        self.units = units

        self.embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)
        self.lstm1 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(self.units,
                                          return_sequences=True,
                                          return_state=True,
                                          recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform')
        self.lstm2 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(self.units,
                                          return_sequences=True,
                                          return_state=True,
                                          recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform')
        self.fc1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.units)
        self.fc2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(vocab_size)

        self.visual_attention = Attention(self.units)
        self.reflective_attention = Attention(self.units)

    def call(self, x, features, hidden_state1, hidden_state2):
        # x shape after passing through embedding == (batch_size, 1, embedding_dim)
        x = self.embedding(x)

        # x shape after concatenation == (batch_size, 1, embedding_dim + hidden_size)
        x = tf.concat([tf.expand_dims(hidden_state1, 1), x], axis=-1)

        # passing through lstm
        output1, hidden_state1, cell_state1 = self.lstm1(x)

        # visual attention as a separate model
        context_vector_v, attention_weights_v = self.visual_attention(features, hidden_state1)

        # change hidden state dimension
        hidden_state2 = tf.concat([tf.expand_dims(hidden_state2, 1), x], axis=-1)

        # x shape after concatenation == (batch_size, 1, embedding_dim + hidden_size)
        x = tf.concat([tf.expand_dims(context_vector_v, 1), hidden_state2], axis=-1)

        # passing the concatenated vector to the lstm
        output2, hidden_state2, cell_state2 = self.lstm2(x)

        # reflective attention as a separate model
        context_vector_r, attention_weights_r = self.reflective_attention(hidden_state2, hidden_state1)

        # shape == (batch_size, max_length, hidden_size)
        x = self.fc1(output2)

        # x shape == (batch_size * max_length, hidden_size)
        x = tf.reshape(x, (-1, x.shape[2]))

        # output shape == (batch_size * max_length, vocab)
        x = self.fc2(x)

        # pass through softmax
        x = tf.nn.softmax(x)

        return x, hidden_state1, hidden_state2, attention_weights_v, attention_weights_r

    def reset_state(self, batch_size):
        return tf.zeros((batch_size, self.units))
encoder = CNN_Encoder(embedding_dim)
decoder = RDN_Decoder(embedding_dim, units, vocab_size)
```

When I use this model for training, I get the following error:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- ResourceExhaustedError                    Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-63-e33dbe296f4b> in <module>()
     12 
     13     for (batch, (img_tensor, target)) in enumerate(dataset):
---> 14         batch_loss, t_loss = train_step(img_tensor, target)
     15         total_loss += t_loss
     16 

13 frames <ipython-input-62-b355d0692cf8> in train_step(img_tensor, target)
     15         for i in range(1, target.shape[1]):
     16             # passing the features through the decoder
---> 17             predictions, hidden_state1, hidden_state2, _, _ = decoder(dec_input, features, hidden_state1, hidden_state2)
     18 
     19             loss += loss_function(target[:, i], predictions)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    966           with base_layer_utils.autocast_context_manager(
    967               self._compute_dtype):
--> 968             outputs = self.call(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    969           self._handle_activity_regularization(inputs, outputs)
    970           self._set_mask_metadata(inputs, outputs, input_masks)

<ipython-input-57-83f30c4f738b> in call(self, x, features, hidden_state1, hidden_state2)
     80 
     81         # passing the concatenated vector to the lstm
---> 82         output2, hidden_state2, cell_state2 = self.lstm2(x)
     83 
     84         # reflective attention as a separate model

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent.py in __call__(self, inputs, initial_state, constants, **kwargs)
    652 
    653     if initial_state is None and constants is None:
--> 654       return super(RNN, self).__call__(inputs, **kwargs)
    655 
    656     # If any of `initial_state` or `constants` are specified and are Keras

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    966           with base_layer_utils.autocast_context_manager(
    967               self._compute_dtype):
--> 968             outputs = self.call(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    969           self._handle_activity_regularization(inputs, outputs)
    970           self._set_mask_metadata(inputs, outputs, input_masks)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent_v2.py in call(self, inputs, mask, training, initial_state)    1179         if can_use_gpu:    1180           last_output, outputs, new_h, new_c, runtime = gpu_lstm(
-> 1181               **gpu_lstm_kwargs)    1182         else:    1183           last_output, outputs, new_h, new_c, runtime = standard_lstm(

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent_v2.py in gpu_lstm(inputs, init_h, init_c, kernel, recurrent_kernel, bias, mask, time_major, go_backwards, sequence_lengths)    1390       biases=array_ops.split(full_bias, 8),    1391       shape=constant_op.constant([-1]),
-> 1392       transpose_weights=True)    1393     1394   if mask is not None:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent_v2.py in _canonical_to_params(weights, biases, shape, transpose_weights)    1234     return array_ops.transpose(w) if transpose_weights else w    1235 
-> 1236   weights = [array_ops.reshape(convert(x), shape) for x in weights]    1237   biases = [array_ops.reshape(x, shape) for x in biases]    1238   return array_ops.concat(weights + biases, axis=0)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent_v2.py in <listcomp>(.0)    1234     return array_ops.transpose(w) if transpose_weights else w    1235 
-> 1236   weights = [array_ops.reshape(convert(x), shape) for x in weights]    1237   biases = [array_ops.reshape(x, shape) for x in biases]    1238   return array_ops.concat(weights + biases, axis=0)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent_v2.py in convert(w)    1232   """    1233   def convert(w):
-> 1234     return array_ops.transpose(w) if transpose_weights else w    1235     1236   weights = [array_ops.reshape(convert(x), shape) for x in weights]

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py in transpose(a, perm, name, conjugate)    2127     else:    2128       perm = np.arange(rank - 1, -1, -1, dtype=np.int32)
-> 2129     return transpose_fn(a, perm, name=name)    2130     2131 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py in transpose(x, perm, name)   11176         pass  # Add nodes to the TensorFlow graph.   11177     except _core._NotOkStatusException as e:
> 11178       _ops.raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)   11179   # Add nodes to the TensorFlow graph.   11180   _, _, _op, _outputs =
_op_def_library._apply_op_helper(

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)    6651   message = e.message + (" name: " + name if name is not None else "")    6652   # pylint: disable=protected-access
-> 6653   six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)    6654   # pylint: enable=protected-access    6655 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[1024,1024] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc [Op:Transpose]
```

Please tell how to correctly implement it (I guess the main problem is in implementation of LSTM). Any help will be highly appreciated.

If you want to try, please use this Google Colab [link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1A2F73rMArHEwhNK8xQH1eFQHL42miCYX?usp=sharing) (as generation of data and training code are lengthy, I cannot put everything in here, it will be clumpsy).
You just have to run the cells in order.

Comment: Could you share a minimal training code, with which I can reproduce the issue? It will be helpful in debugging the issue.

Comment: It's will be very lengthy to put in here, so I have added a Google Colab [link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1A2F73rMArHEwhNK8xQH1eFQHL42miCYX?usp=sharing), you can use this. Just run the cells in order.

Comment: Hi, could you remove the @tf.function decoration on the train_step function as discussed here https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33308. If it does not work it might be due to another issue then, Best

Comment: Thanks it helps, now I am getting different error 'too many values to unpack' in lstm.

Comment: Yes I got same error now. The output of the lstm cell should be reduced - remove the cell_state1 for example. Best

Comment: make return_state = True. It will work. But now a different error , dimension problem, I am working,

Comment: ok. Nice. The dimension error should be solvable . Best

Comment: yes, but now OOM error, I have modified the question, You can directly copy paste the new model and check. I am also adding new colab link

Comment: For OOM issues, the one thing that might help is to reduce the batch size.

Answer (score 2):

With OOM issue, there is not much of one can do, there lies two options from my perspective.

1. To get a better machine or rent a cloud service that can provide you with more RAM.
2. Reduce your network, I tried with the following Hyperparamters and the training works.

`BATCH_SIZE = 8`, `embedding_dim = 512`, `units = 512`. Remaining all the Hyperparameters are the same

You will have to play around to understand which is the biggest network that can fit in your machine.